# TensorFlow `True` and `False` booleans

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a more TensorFlow-nic way to get a [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) boolean than `tf.constant(True)` and `tf.constant(False)`? A sort of `tf.True` or `tf.False` (that do no exist).

Comment: Do you find `tf.constant(True)` / `tf.constant(False)` "bad" for some reason? Consider that TF values must be created within a graph, so they cannot possibly be static constants. You could maybe have functions like `tf.true()` / `tf.false()`, but it would really be the same as `tf.ones` / `tf.zeros` with `dtype=tf.bool`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `tf.constant(True)` /  `tf.constant(False)`, I was trying `tf.cond(True, ..., ...)` and got the following error: `TypeError: pred must not be a Python bool` so I was just wondering. But your point about static constants makes sense.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you mean, yes that is actually annoying, I've had that too with code that I wanted to work either with a TF bool or a Python bool. I get that the point is to save the TF conditional if you can, but still... I think I use `tf.convert_to_tensor` for that kind of thing... Unfortunately there are several things in TF that require you to be quite less succinct than one may hope for.